# Laravel 4 - How to get the data from the foreign table from each item in collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relationship

I have a `StandardOverall` table with the following columns:

```
sto_id | sto_transaction_id | sto_standard_id | sto_count | sto_total
```

and a `Standard` table with the following columns:

```
std_standards_id | std_code | std_description | std_notes
```

`sto_standard_id` in `StandardOverall` table  is the foreign key to `std_standards_id` in the `Standard` table.

I return all the rows from the `StandardOverall` table that belong to a `sto_transaction_id`. How can I return the data from the foreign table as well, all in one collection? This code is in the controller:

```
$transactionID = Session::get('transactionID');
$standardStats = StandardOverall::whereID($transactionID)->get();
```

The `StandardOverall` Model:

```
class StandardOverall extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'sto_stat_overall';
    protected $primaryKey = 'sto_id';


    public function Standards() {
        return  $this->belongsTo('Standards');
    }

    public function getStandards() {
        return $this->hasOne('Standards', 'std_standards_id', 'sto_standard_id')->with('std_description');
    }

    public function scopewhereID($query, $transactionID) {
         return $query->where('sto_transaction_id', $transactionID);
    }
}
```

So I want the count and total columns from standards overall table and the linked code and description from the standard table. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$transactionID = Session::get('transactionID');

$standardStats = StandardOverall::with(['standards' => function($query) {

    $query->select(
       'std_standards_id', 'std_code', 'std_description', DB::raw('count(*) as count')
    )->groupBy('std_standards_id');

}])->whereID($transactionID)->get();
```